# How to add a message object to API with FLASK

Tags: python, api, flask

I have a task to create a REST API that will be responsible for handling messages. As a part of the functionality, I should be able to write a message. This message should contain the following fields:

- id
- sender
- receiver
- message itself
- subject
- creation date

So, as I expected to do this is to have a route that should handle the object that I will send as an argument. But I am not sure I can do so. What would you recommend in this case?

For now, I can handle it somehow like this:

```
@app.route('/new_message/<string:sender>/<string:receiver>/<string:message>/',  methods=['POST'])
def get_message(sender, receiver, message):
    sender = sender
    receiver = receiver
    message = message

    # Code that will add the data or to the database or to the json file
    # if I decide not to implement DB for this task
    
    return 'Sent successfully'
```

Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am suggesting you to use JSON request body instead of the `path parameters` for the POST method.

Here is the example,

```
from flask import request, Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/new_message',  methods=['POST'])
def get_message():

   payload = request.json()
   sender = payload['sender']
   receiver = payload['receiver']
   message = payload['message']

   return 'Sent successfully'

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run()
```

Now, If you want to add message as object then you can add it in JSON body. Not only message object you can add any number of fields if required.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! it helped!